# SQLAlchemy retrieve rows with no corresponding objects via foreign key

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've tried a number of variations of this including exists, count/group by and can't seem to get this to work correctly.

I've got the following model:

```
class Image(db.Model):
 id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
 file_name = db.Column(db.String(128))
 part_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('part.id'))

class Part(db.Model):
 id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
 make = db.Column(db.String(128), default='')
 model = db.Column(db.String(128), default='')
 images = db.relationship('Image')
```

I'm trying to get all Parts that have no images yet. This code didn't work correctly:

```
p = db.session.query(Part, func.count(Image.id)).join(Image).group_by(Part).having(func.count(Image.id) == 0).all()
```

Comment: What is not working. Can you post sql generated by ORM as well?

Comment: Have you tried `outerjoin` instead of `join`? Inner join returns only those parts that have images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`any()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/internals.html#sqlalchemy.orm.properties.RelationshipProperty.Comparator.any) to test the existence of related rows. For example:

```
parts = session.query(Part).filter(~Part.images.any())
```